# mocking RPC context coming from RabbitMq in jest, nestjs

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, rabbitmq, nestjs

I'm trying to write unit tests for my controller in nestjs, here's the source of my controller:

```
import { Controller, Inject, Logger } from '@nestjs/common'
import { CONTEXT, MessagePattern, RequestContext } from '@nestjs/microservices'

import { CustomersService } from './customer.service'

@Controller("customers")
export class CustomersController {
  constructor(
    @Inject(CONTEXT)
    private ctx: RequestContext,
    private readonly customersService: CustomersService
  ) {}


  @MessagePattern("ticketing_customer_actions")
  async customersActions(): Promise<RpcResult> {
    const data = this.ctx.data;

    if (data.customerInfo.expire_date) {
      try {
            "REST OF THE CODE ....."
```

`data` is the where the json comes to my controller from the rabbitmq, so I need to mock `this.ctx.data` and that's what I do not know how to do. I mocked my service with just giving my service path to the `jest.mock()` function.

Here's my test so far:

```
jest.mock("../Customers/customer.service.ts");
describe("CustomersController", () => {
  let controller: CustomersController;
  let service: CustomersService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [CustomersController],
      providers: [CustomersService],
    }).compile();
    service = module.get<CustomersService>(CustomersService);
    controller = module.get<CustomersController>(CustomersController);
  });

  it("should be defined", () => {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });

  it("CustomersActions", async () => {
    const result = new RpcResult({});
    jest
      .spyOn(service, "customersActions")
      .mockImplementation(async () => result);
    expect(await controller.customersActions()).toBe(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: What is `this.ctx`?

Comment: the context I injected in my class, there's a nest library providing this so I use it to obtain data from RabbitMq, I Updated my post, check it again for more clarifications,